# With a {locale} on each routes, my links (in my menu) for change the locale variable must have the rights parameters for each routes, so

Tags: php, laravel

After hours of research, I ended up creating a solution myself, it works, but I think you'll laugh.

Does anyone have a better idea?

```
     @foreach(localization()->getSupportedLocales() as $key => $locale)
        <li class="nav-item lang">
          <a class="{{ (app()->getLocale() == $key) ? 'active' : '' }}" href=
          "@php 
              $url = url()->full();
              $url = explode("/", $url);
              $newUrl = '';
              $first = reset( $url );
              foreach($url as $urlKey => $value)
              {
                $slash = '/';
                if($urlKey == 0)
                  $slash = '/';
                else
                  $slash = '/';
                if($urlKey == 3)
                  $url[$urlKey] = $key;
                  if( !next( $url ) && $value != $first) {
                    $slash = '';
                  }
                $newUrl .=  $url[$urlKey].$slash;
              }

              echo($newUrl);

            @endphp">{{ strtoupper($key) }}</a>
        </li>
      @endforeach
```

As I know that the $locale variable is always at the 3rd slash of my url, I had fun with an explode, and I have the expected result, a variable url with a random number of parameters depending on the current route.

But something tells me you're going to laugh... Am I right? ^^

I tried this code, but I need :

1 - Advice on where to create this function

2 - A better idea to achieve the same result?

Thanks by advance all !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about addding name to the routes like:

```
Route::get('/{locale}/dashboard')->name('dashboard');
```

then add the value of locale when you want to use that route:

```
@foreach(localization()->getSupportedLocale() as $key => $value)
    <a class="{{ app()->getLocale() == $key ? 'active' : '' }}" 
       href="{{ route('dashboard', ['locale' => $key]) }}">
    {{ strtoupper($key) }}
    </a>
@endforeach
```

so the key player here is the route() helper since you can pass the name of the route on the as the first argument then the {}'s value in the route as the second argument.

Comment: Good idee ! Finally i've done this with localization :
          @foreach(localization()->getSupportedLocales() as $key => $locale)
            <li class="nav-item lang">
              <a class="flag-icon-{{($key == 'en') ? 'gb' : $key}} {{ (app()->getLocale() == $key) ? 'active' : '' }}" href=
              "{{ localization()->getLocalizedURL($key) }}"></a>
            </li>
          @endforeach